# How do I automate creation of an ODBC connection in the system DSN?

Tags: windows, deployment, odbc

I need to create an ODBC connection in System DSN on a bunch of windows machines.  What can I do to make this process simpler than manually typing the details into the Create New Datasource Wizard on each machine?  Something like a *.reg file I can just double click on would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is stored in

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources
```

— **Source:** [Petri - ODBC System DSN Creation](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=12533) (Check it, there is a script)

Comment: For future comers: there are two parts to this. The key above contains a list of data sources.  Each data source in the list also has it's own key (folder) in either `HKLM\SOFWARE\ODBC\ODBCI.INI` or `HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI`.  So, in a nutshell, don't forget to check Current User as well as local machine (some things only work in one or the other) and don't forgot to copy both parts.

Comment: Also, on 64-bit systems there are two separate odbc connection registrations, so you also need to look in `\\HKLM\Software\WoW6432Node\ODBC\` if you want your entry to be available to 32bit programs.

Comment: Finally, if you want you want to store a password with your entry, you'll have to look somewhere else. There's no way I've found to set a password here, even an encrypted one.

Comment: Also, Tom, I'd like your permission/action to edit this additional info into the answer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Go ahead, you have permission.